# Upserting in Mongo DB and the Id problem

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a problem while upserting to mongo db using the official C# driver.

```
public abstract class AggregateRoot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All mongoDb documents must have an id, we specify it here
    /// </summary>
    protected AggregateRoot()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

My entities already have the id-s but I had to create the mongo specific Id for it to work, as all the documents in a collection should have one. Now then I receive a new entity in my system a new Mongo Id is generated and I get the **mongo cannot change _id of a document old** exception. Is there some work-around?

> Let me describe the design a bit. All the entities which would be
>   stored as documents were inheriting from AggregateRoot which had the
>   id generation in it. Every sub-document had its id generated
>   automatically and I had no problem with this. The id in AggregateRoot
>   was introduced to correct the problem when retrieving data from
>   MongoCollection to List and the generation was introduced so the id-s
>   are different. Now we can move that id generation to save methods
>   because the new entity for update had a new id generation. But it
>   would mean that every dev on the team must not forget generating id-s
>   in repository which is risky. It would be nicer just to ignore the id
>   than mapping from mongo if it is possible and not to have
>   AggregateRoot class at all

Comment: How are you saving your objects?  The BsonId attribute should force MongoDB to use that field as your id.

Comment: The idea is that the data comes from an external system for storage. It has its own id-s I have to store. And this is a fake id for the sake of Mongo compatibility. Every document inherits from AggregateRoot, so this thing is generated on receiving every object. It is clear that I might receive the same data but the generated mongo id is different. So the exception appears

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you might be explicitly setting the `Id` value for both inserts and updates.  That's fine for inserts, all new objects need an `_id` value, however for updates you're not allowed to change the value of `_id` on an existing document after it's created.

Try not setting the `Id` value at all.  If you don't specify a value before inserting, the driver uses built-in `IdGenerator` classes to generate a new _id value, so if it's an ObjectId type it'll use the `ObjectIdGenerator`.  Then both your inserts and updates work fine.

Comment: If I remove the id property then really it is not a problem saving/updating an entity. The problem is that it throws exception when I try to search on the collection from the code because it cannot map the _id to an inexisting property

Comment: You can use the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute on the class if the collection has fields that don't have matching properties.

Comment: Also [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] must be used in addition to your solution as @renadeen explained

Answer (score 86):

I've encountered similar problem.
I wanted to upsert documents using official C# driver. I had a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

In console I would write: `db.collection.update({Field1: 3},{Field1: 3, Field2: "value"})` and it would work. In C# I wrote:

```
collection.Update(Query.EQ("Field1", 3),
                Update.Replace(new MyClass { Field1 = 3, Field2 = "value" }),
                UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

and it didn't work! Because driver includes empty id in update statement and when I upsert second document with different value of Field1 exception `E11000 duplicate key error index` is thrown (in this case Mongo tries to insert a document with _id that already exists in db).

When I generated _id by myself (like topic starter) I've encountered the same exception (`mongo cannot change _id of a document`) on upserting objects with existing value of Field1.

**Solution** is to mark Id property by attribute `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` (and not initialize it). In this case driver omits _id field in update statement and MongoDb generates Id if it necessary.

Comment: You rule man, that [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] saved a ton of time. It is a shame I can vote more for you.

Comment: Wasted about an hour trying to figure out why my ReplaceOneAsync call with the 2.0 driver wasn't working.  Found this answer.  Added [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] and problem solved.  Thanks!

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure this out. THANKS!

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: There is one big "gotcha" here, this doesn't work if you filter on the _id: [Mongodb jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1805)  `Just to reiterate, if the filter includes the _id then the server will always use that value as the _id of the new document if no existing document matches and the ReplaceOne call results in an upsert. This is true even if the value of the _id in the filter is null (or an empty ObjectId).`

Comment: This should be the solution. Thanks

Comment: tnx bro,you saved my time

Comment: This is now the second time this answer saved me from a terrible headache. Thank you!