# MongoDB .NET not generating _id on upsert

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm attempting to upsert a document into MongoDB 2.4.4 using the .NET driver. It seems not to automatically generate the `_id` on upserts, though it does correctly generate the `_id` on plain inserts. How can I cause the driver to properly generate the `_id`?

Here is a small example that demonstrates the problem.

```
public class MongoObject
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string MongoID { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}

var obj = new MongoObject()
{
    Index = 1
};

//This inserts the document, but with a _id set to Null
_collection.Update(Query.EQ("Index", BsonValue.Create(1)), Update.Replace(obj), UpdateFlags.Upsert, new WriteConcern() { Journal = true });

//This inserts the document with the expected autogenerated _id
//_collection.Insert(obj);
```

Comment: I'm curious what the downvote was for? Since someone just went through and downvoted two other questions that I answered myself, I'll just point out that that is actually a fully supported feature of StackOverflow. There's even a checkbox for "answer your own question - share your knowledge Q&A style" on the "Ask a question" form.

Comment: Karma restored. This is a useful question with a useful answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

And of course I find the answer immediately after posting the question. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626884/76263), the solution is to add a `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` attribute to the ID. In the example from the question it would be:

```
public class MongoObject
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]    // <--- this is what was missing
    public string MongoID { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```