# C# MongoDB: How can I map a domain object (BsonIgnoreIfDefault needed on Id property)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, domain-driven-design, mongodb-.net-driver

I have started a small and simple project (a very primitive blog) to get some hands-on experience with DDD and while I believe I understand the basic concepts I have not been able to solve the following problem yet.

Given a POCO object 'post' I would like to persist it using a repository, implemented using mongodb collection.update method with an upsert parameter (see code below)

```
public Post Save(Post p)
{
    var wc = collection.Update(
    Query<Post>.EQ<string>(p0 => p0.permalink, p.permalink),
    Update<Post>.Replace(p),
    UpdateFlags.Upsert);
    return p;
}
```

However it appears to be necessary to apply a mongodb-specific attribute to your Id field in order for upsert to work correctly, as detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224022/741695

As a result I can only see two likely courses of action:

1) add a reference to mongodb assemblies to my domain library project, but does not feel right since mongodb is repository implementation detail (and thus belongs in a DAL)

2) pass a 'post' instance (poco domain object) to the PostRepository implementation and handle any implementation-related issues there by mapping domain objects to and from DTOs

While the second solution seems to be in line with DDD principles it is also more expensive to implement than the first one, so I am left wondering whether there is an even better alternative.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the attribute to map the Id, you can't do that in your DAL with `RegisterClassMap`:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(p => p.Id));
});
```

BTW: You can do an upsert without mapping the Id, you just can't use the simple `Update<Post>.Replace(p)`. You need to create an update yourself.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'You need to create an update yourself' ? I am not sure I understand what you mean, thanks in advance!

Comment: When you use `Update<Post>.Replace(p)` It creates an update query that replaces all the fields with the new data based on the _id field. It's a classic upsert where you take a new object with the same ID and just override all the fields. You sometimes need a different approach that doesn't simply override everything. You can do that when you give a specific query you build yourself.

The first option is better though.

Comment: I extended your answer by adding

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(p => p.Id).SetIgnoreIfDefault(true));
});

This allows me to insert two documents, however I cannot read them back since i get a 'Cannot deserialize Guid from BsonType ObjectId' exception

Comment: @AndreaScarcella You don't want to insert 2 with the same id. you want one, you just need to specify which field holds the id. The id itself, of course must be either a new unique one (which means a new document), or an existing id (which means an existing item).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45515/discussion-between-andrea-scarcella-and-i3arnon)

Comment: Summary: Thanks to I3arnon's help a new requirement has emerged that will be addressed in a new question, the solution presented in accepted answer does not generate a new id on upsert.

Comment: @AndreaScarcella Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem where I don't want to mix the Domain and DAL logic but have found Ids are only generated on InsertOne() and not for Upserts with ReplaceOne() using driver version 2.2.3. Also my Ids are of type Guid in this case.

Comment: @Shane: I implemented a factory (domain layer) and used it to assign new entities a Guid on creation. This way i always have a valid entity (advantage #1) without a database call (advantage #2).

Comment: @AndreaScarcella Thanks for your response.