# MongoDb custom Id generator does not get called

Tags: c#, mongodb

In my application I have a POCO class called `Parameter` which is imported from a .csv file and stored in a mongodb collection. As the POCO class is used in projects outside of my repository project, I do not wish to use ObjectId as Id, which would make it neccessary to add references to MongoDb all over the place, where there should be none. Now, There are two different types of Parameters, non-numerical and numerical. The former have a unique code that may look like this `A013` or this `104`, the latter have none, so I thought I might use the code for the non-numerical parameters as Id and well, just anything for the numericals. In the end I tried to get a string representation of a Guid for the sake of simplicity (ha!) by not having to manage any numbers or anything. However, I struggle to get it working.

So here's the result:

```
public class Parameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public ParameterType ParameterType { get; set; }
}
```

And this is happening during the import of numerical parameters:

```
.Select((columnName, index) => new Parameter()
                               {
                                   Name = columnName,
                                   Unit = columnUnits[index],
                                   ParameterType = ParameterType.TestResult
                               })
.ForEach(parameter =>
{
    parameterCollection.ReplaceOne(Builders<Parameter>.Filter
                                                      .Eq("Name", parameter.Name),
                                   parameter,
                                   new UpdateOptions()
                                   {
                                       IsUpsert = true
                                   });
});
```

Using the Parameter class you can see atop results in an exception upon import:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: 'A write operation resulted in an error.
>     E11000 duplicate key error collection: timeSeriesDb.Parameters index: *id* dup key: { : null }'

Awkwardly enough, MongoDb recognizes the Id as Id but simply inserts the null value instead of complaining that Id can't be null. Hence the exception is logical as none of the parameters has an id.

So I tried using a custom id generator:

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringGuidGenerator))]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

With the Generator being this:

```
public class StringGuidGenerator : IIdGenerator
{
    public object GenerateId(object container, object document)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public bool IsEmpty(object id)
    {
        return id == null;
    }
}
```

However, the import still throws the exact same error, because the generator never gets called. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223894/mongodb-net-not-generating-id-on-upsert) question `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` is missing but adding that results in an error when trying to receive the data as MongoDb now simply ignores the Id field **and** generator and adds its own default ObjectId to the inserted objects which it then cannot convert back.

```
return this.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Parameter>("Parameters")
                         .Find(Builders<Parameter>.Filter.Empty)
                         .ToList();
```

> System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class TSI.Data.DTO.Parameter: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.'

If I create the Id myself before adding the data to the document, it works. However, if I try to import the same .csv file a second time I'm getting the following exception:

```
.Select((columnName, index) => new Parameter()
                               {
                                   Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                   Name = columnName,
                                   Unit = columnUnits[index],
                                   ParameterType = ParameterType.TestResult
                               })
.ForEach(/* blabla replaceone blabla */)
```

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: 'A write operation resulted in an error.
>     After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: "05e94906-ab03-4dd1-b953-29fab850e267"'

Which obviously means that MongoDb does not actually remove and insert upon calling ReplaceOne but actually somehow tries to change the entry in question as if I called UpdateOne and thus tries to change the immutable Id to the new value. wha... I don't even ...

Ok so, I also tried the following, which actually does work ... for numerical parameters, which do not have a predefined Id. Luckily, non-numerical parameters come from a predefined lookup table and are actually not imported, otherwise I'd guess this would cause more exceptions. It does create a string representation of a MongoDb ObjectId, instead of my desired Guid but as long as this does not cause trouble elsewhere I'm okay with it.

```
public class Parameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Id { get; set; }
...
```

However, I'd really like to know why my custom id generator does not work and what do I have to do to get it to work? And also what is the difference between UpdateOne and ReplaceOne?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the root of all your problems is that key field (`Id`) does not actually play a role of a key: you don't match the items by this field during update (matching by `Name`) and you generate the new value for this field each time the object is updated which causes expected problems.

Finally you got a workable solution, but how does this model

```
public class Parameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

satisfies your original requirement:

> ... I do not wish to use ObjectId as Id, which would make it
>   neccessary to add references to MongoDb all over the place, where
>   there should be none.

All those attributes are defined in MongoDB.Bson library that still adds coupling of your model to MongoDB.

From your import logic, seems like `Name` is a true key for `Parameter` model. Otherwise, replacing the whole document based on `Name` filter does not make much sense.
In this case the best option is to remove syntetic `Id` property and nominate `Name` as id field.

The easiest way would be renaming `Parameter.Name` to `Parameter.Id`. In this case the only remaining change in your code would be updating the field name in the filter:

```
Builders<Parameter>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, parameter.Id);
```

If you want however to keep this property as `Name`, you could achieve this by marking the property with `BsonId` attribute:

```
public class Parameter
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Or, if you want to keep your original requirement of a model not coupled with MongoDB library, you could use class mapping. Call following mapping before first call to `Parameter` collection:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Parameter>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdMember(x => x.Name);
});
```

I believe this is a much cleaner approach, which will fix your current errors and will protect you from other potential problems in the future.

Here are the answers for the rest of your questions if you are still interested:

> ... why my custom id generator does not work and what do I have to do
>   to get it to work?

Your `StringGuidGenerator` will work perfectly fine when you insert new document into collection. However `IdGenerator` is just not used during document update. The reason is that updating of id field is not allowed in MongoDB. So you should either have a correctly filled id in document you pass for update or to mark the id field with `BsonIgnoreIfDefault` so that Id field is not passed with update command. However the later scenario will not work for upsert if document does not exist. Unfortunatelly, MongoDB .Net Driver can not know whether the document exist or not when it sends upsert command. That's why `IdGenerator` will not play well with upserts.

> ... what is the difference between UpdateOne and ReplaceOne?

When calling `ReplaceOne` method, you provide the full replacement document. All document fields will be updated with new ones.

`UpdateOne` method allows more specific document change. You provide a set of fields that you are going to update. All other document fields aren't touched. Here is a sample of `UpdateOne` method call:

```
parameterCollection.UpdateOne(Builders<Parameter>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Name, "SomeName"),
    Builders<Parameter>.Update
        .Set(q => q.Name, "New name")
        .Set(q => q.Unit, "New unit")
);
```

Comment: Well, my database is empty initially. I'm calling ReplaceOne with IsUpsert set to true, so new documents get inserted if they cannot be found. This does happen, but without using my custom IdGenerator ... is it really only called when I use the Insert function? If so, that's horrible design and not what I'd be expecting.

Comment: Your explanation of the difference between UpdateOne and ReplaceOne does not explain why the latter would throw this error of a manipulated id. In fact, I'd still not expect it, just as I didn't in the first place.

Comment: Regarding your first comment - in both cases (document exist or not) MongoDB Driver sends update command with upsert flag. It just can't know whether such document exist or not.

Comment: Regarding the second comment - document ids are immutable. You provide a document with different Id for replacement which causes the exception.

Comment: So I reason that ReplaceOne is actually a form of UpdateOne, which simply updates all fields? So if I want to have a real ReplaceOne (i.e. delete one entry and insert the new one) I have to actually manually do it? Wow ... that really is unexpected. And yes, in this case the second comment is self explanatory.

Comment: "So I reason that ReplaceOne is actually a form of UpdateOne, which simply updates all fields?" - correct. "So if I want to have a real ReplaceOne (i.e. delete one entry and insert the new one) I have to actually manually do it?" - Why would you want to have such "real" replace? MongoDB behavior is true document replacement. In your case it causes the problems because you are trying to replace document id. This is consequence of incorrect selection of document key. Just reconsider your document definition as I suggested in the answer, and you will be OK with replace behavior.

Comment: "MongoDB behavior is true document replacement." That's very debatable. If you have a broken machine, you put it away, buy a new one and use that instead, you clearly have replaced the machine. If you remove the broken part inside that machine and insert a new one, did you replace the machine? Is it a new one? No, it clearly isn't. Then again, if you replace every single part of the machine one after another, in the end nothing of the old machine remains, but is it really a new one? When in the process did the machine become new? When could it still be considered the old?

Comment: Anyway, that question was purely theoretical, not that I actually wanted to do it ;) I will indeed consider your suggestion and mark it as answer. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: This is one hecka underrated answer, particularly using RegisterClassMap to decouple your model from MongoDB.Driver.