# MongoDB: Trouble with child class with an overridden ID and attribute

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm having big problems when I'm overriding the `Id` property in a derived class in my MongoDB storage setup.

The base class that all of my data models inherit looks like this:

```
public abstract class DataModel
{
     [BsonId]
     [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
     public virtual string Id { get; set; }

     public DateTime Created { get; set; }

     public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

     public DateTime Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Then there are a few particular child data models that use **upserts**. This requires me to annotate the overridden `Id` property with `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224022/633098):

```
public class ChildDataModel : DataModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]          //  <---- need this for Upserts to work
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    ... // child-specific properties
}
```

But unfortunately it results in this error:

> The property 'Id' of type
>   'Namespace.ChildDataModel' cannot
>   use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property
>   'Id' of type 'Namespace.DataModel'.

I've tried registering class maps, adding a type discriminator with `RootClass = true` on the base model, as well as defining my child data models on the base class with the special `[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ChildDataModel), ...)]` attribute, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I worked with inherited classes some time ago, in this scenario I just had the Id in the base class, do you really Id in the child class?

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB driver by convention tries to map all the properties named `Id` into `_id` in class map. As you have two classes it registers the `_id` twice. What's more `BsonIgnoreIfDefault` would work fine if the `Id` was `null` but here it's not since the driver automatically will generate the value when you insert new document.

To fix that you can use `BsonIgnore` if you want to have single `_id` in MongoDB

```
public class ChildDataModel : DataModel
{        
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnore]
    public override string Id { get; set; }
}
```

will be stored as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb5fe72e2a22b3848b6a1f6"),
    "Created" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:10:25.908Z"),
    "Modified" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:10:25.914Z"),
    "Deleted" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:10:25.914Z")
}
```

or you can use `BsonNoId` attribute if you want to have two values stored separately:

```
[BsonNoId]
public class ChildDataModel : DataModel
{        
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public override string Id { get; set; }
}
```

will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb5fecde2a22b3088ef731c"),
    "Created" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:11:56.810Z"),
    "Modified" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:11:56.822Z"),
    "Deleted" : ISODate("2019-04-16T16:11:56.822Z"),
    "Id" : ObjectId("5cb5fecde2a22b3088ef731c")
}
```

however it's still the same value from application point of view

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the solutions worked. In the first case, a `ReplaceOneAsync` does not generate an Id. In the second one, neither `_id` or `Id`is populated, both are serialized as `null`.

Comment: @silkfire I tried with `Insert`, I guess in other cases toy need to generate it on your own

Comment: So only in this particular situation then? Cos a `ReplaceOneAsync` with a model annotated with `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` works if you don't deal with inherited models like I did here.

Comment: That gave me this error instead: `A write operation resulted in an error.
  After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5cb6eb199764726f1437387e')`. It doesn't seem to like that I'm generating it manually.