# c# mongo db replace one Id issue

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using driver 2.21. I need to implement an upsert for a given data that has `ObjectId Id` field. I am using AutoMap() and I tried adding `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` attribute on the `Id` field.

The code goes as follow:

```
var m = _mapper.Map<TStorage>(s);
var filter = Builders<TStorage>.Filter.Eq(e => e.Id, m.Id);
var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, m, new ReplaceOptions
{
    IsUpsert = true
});
```

When I create a new data, it will insert it with _id = 00000000000. How can I make it work so that _id is autogenerated when `Id == ObjectId.Empty`?

I have tried to change my class map logic:

```
m.AutoMap();
m.MapMember(e => e.Id).SetIgnoreIfDefaault(true);
```

I also tried to add `[BsonIgnoreIdDefault]` on top of `Id` but it does not work.

I have checked the scenario where I have an empty collection, so replace would result in an upsert. The `UpsertedId` value is 00000000000.

When I use `InsertOneAsync` api, the Id is auto-generated.

Comment: I think according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7283992/14182561 from a similar question the combination of [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] and [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] should help